# How can I install a prepopulated Realm database into a Flutter application?

Tags: flutter, realm

I have a Flutter application that uses a pre-populated Realm database. Running  `flutter run -d <some-device>` only install the app without the pre-populated database. How can I install the pre-populated Realm database into a mobile device together with the Flutter app?

Comment: Generally speaking, you would bundle it with your app. There are docs for how to do that in a variety of languages and platforms, here's the Swift version [Bundling a Realm](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/realm-files/bundle-a-realm/?_ga=2.10023029.1313716567.1659791634-762773769.1656853287)

Comment: @Jay I looking for a Dart/Flutter version of that.

Comment: Bundling a realm is a function of your environment. On iOS for example, a realm file is created and then either dragged into XCode or added as a project Resource. On android it would be copied into a project directory called assets. It's then built as part of the project. The process is really platform (not language) specific.